# Send multi values ​to an OpenQuery

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the following query in sql server

Example:

> ```
> Declare @typeL varchar(max) 
> SET @typeL = 'AA,NF' 
> OPENQUERY(ORACLEPD, 'SELECT * FROM Ledger where typeLedger in (''+@typeL+'')')
> ```

But it shows me an error since it does not receive dynamic parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made my own solution. (it worked for me)

```
DECLARE @var VARCHAR(MAX)  
DECLARE @var2 VARCHAR(MAX)  
DECLARE @tb as TABLE(       
       VALORES VARCHAR(MAX) )
    
    SET @var = 'AA,NF' 
    SET @var2 = ''
    
    INSERT INTO @tb 
    SELECT value FROM string_split(@var,',')
    
    WHILE EXISTS(SELECT *  FROM @tb) 
            BEGIN
            IF (SELECT COUNT(*)FROM @tb)>1  
               BEGIN    
               SET @var2 = @var2 + (''''+(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM @tb)+'''')+''','''     
               DELETE TOP(1) FROM @tb   
               END      
                  ELSE          
                      BEGIN             
                          SET @var2 = @var2 + (''''+(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM @tb)+'''')                       
                          DELETE TOP(1) FROM @tb            END     END

    
    SELECT @var2
```

The openquery would look like this:

```
OPENQUERY(ORACLEPD, 'SELECT * FROM Ledger where typeLedger in (''+@var2+'')')
```

The result @var2 returns: **'AA'',''NF'**

I share it in case someone needs it.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```sql
Declare @typeL varchar(max) 
SET @typeL = '''AA'',''NF''' 
OPENQUERY(ORACLEPD, 'SELECT * FROM Ledger where typeLedger in ('+@typeL+')')
```

[Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions013.htm)

Comment: Yes and no!, but using the variable @typeL, to make it dynamic